# Return a reference to a method?

Tags: php, oop, reference, static-methods

Example:

```
Class Test {
    private function __construct() {}

    public static function init() {
        $new_test = new Test();
        return $new_test->inner_test;
    }

    public function inner_test() {
        print '!!!!';
    }
}

$test = Test::init();
$test();
```

Returns "PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string"

Is there a way to accomplish this Javascript type behavior in PHP?

Comment: PHP cannot return function references like JS can. Maybe try reading up on http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: @Phil, yes it can...You just assign a variable to a pointer. He was close, but because he assigning a class he has to use an array.

Comment: @Thomas No, it cannot

Comment: You'll need a custom callable wrapper, or wrap it in an anonymous function, else return a `[$this, 'methodname']` pair but invoke it with call_user_func.

Comment: I know call_user_func is usually used, my posted example works just fine.

Comment: @mario `s/$this/$test`

Comment: There is critical detail missing now that I look at it...he didn't state what PHP version he is using...In anything older than PHP5.4 he needs to use call_user_func, grr evolution.

Comment: I don't think PHP works that way, actually what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Below PHP 5.4

```
Class Test {
    private function __construct() {}

    public static function init() {
        $new_test = new Test();
        return $new_test->inner_test();
    }

    public function inner_test() {
        print '!!!!';
    }
}

$test = array('Test','init');
call_user_func($test);
```

For Phil:

```
function test(){
echo "Hello";
}
$test = test;
$test();
```

Run that in the sandbox.

Comment: Now that I look at it, this only works on newer PHP versions, which is what I primarily use.

Comment: That `$test()` syntax is a new one to me. Can't find a documented reference to it though

Comment: Your little example gives me *PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test'*. That is just PHP string expansion. Your example with `$test = ['Test', 'init']; $test()` was cooler

Comment: Yeah, and now that I get the principle of what you really want, won't help (although it is used for callbacks in most frameworks). I now see you want to return inner_test as a value and use it as a callback. Today has been too long for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phil for the link. This works:

```
Class Test {
    private function __construct($myString) {
        $this->myString = $myString;
    }

    public static function init($myString) {
        $new_test = new Test($myString);
        return function() use (&$new_test) {$new_test->inner_test();};
    }

    public function inner_test() {
        print $this->myString;
    }
}

$test = Test::init('Lorem Ipsum Dolar');
$test();
```

Comment: Just as a note, anonymous functions didn't exist until PHP 5.3

Comment: Yep. I won't actually be using this because of that limitation, but it is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Check my answer, I edited it so it will work with any PHP for the most part.